# List permission of specific user in openshift

Tags: openshift, k8s-rolebinding, k8s-cluster-role

I would like to know how to list all the permission belongs to a specific user/ group.

I am using `oc describe clusterrolebinding | grep <user>` and but I don't think that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can check permissions for users or groups.

For listing users

```
oc get users
```

For listing groups

```
oc get groups
```

For specific action/resource for a specific user

```
oc auth can-i create configmap --as=<user>
```

To list all permission for a specific user

```
oc auth can-i --as=<user> --list
```

Same for a groups
Ex.:

```
oc get groups
oc auth can-i --as-group=<group> --list
```

Comment: You might get `error: requesting uid, groups or user-extra for <user>/<host> without impersonating a user` if you specify `--as-group=<group>` without also specifying `--as=<user>` --> `oc auth can-i --as-group=<group> --as=<user> --list`

Answer (score 1):

The OpenShift CLI has [some commands](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/cli_reference/openshift_cli/developer-cli-commands.html) that you can use to get your own permissions in OpenShift:

```
oc auth can-i --list
```

If you want to check if a certain user can perform a certain operation, you can use the following command:

```
oc policy who-can
# Example: oc policy who-can list pods
```

Comment: i think the `oc auth can-i --list` is the one im looking for, but can I run that command for other user?

Comment: `--as` option can  be check a user you would like.
Here is the help from the oc command : `--as='': Username to impersonate for the operation. User could be a regular user or a service account in a
namespace.`